# Create Azure Artifacts universal package feed via Azure API - Example

Tags: azure-artifacts

we want/need to create feeds in an automatic way depending on a configuration file.
Looking at the official documentation neither the Azure CLI nor the Python API provides some convenience functionality to achieve my goal. There is only the REST API that is described briefly in the docs.

Is there anywhere a concrete example for a feed creation via REST API that I can reuse?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Feed Management - Create Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/create%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), to create a feed with specific name:

```
POST https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

With request body:

```
{
    "name": "MyFeedName",
    "hideDeletedPackageVersions": true,
    "upstreamEnabled": true
}
```

Then the feed with name `MyFeedName` will be created:

[image]

For more parameters about request body you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/create%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#request-body).

Comment: Thank you. I have seen the official docs but the request body is huge and it was not clear to me what is required and what not.

Comment: You're welcome~ Yes the request body is huge, so we can choose to only use some necessary parameters.

Comment: How can we set upstreamSources in the request body from api, any references can help me. Been struggling to create a feed (with upstream) using API C#