# Why is there a difference in feed permission settings when Azure artifact feeds are created "via UI" and "via REST API"?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-artifacts

**Using REST API:**

I used the following documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/create%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#feedpermission
to create project scope feed using REST API

And referred
[Create Azure Artifacts universal package feed via Azure API - Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62875730/create-azure-artifacts-universal-package-feed-via-azure-api-example)

Feed was created with the following permissions

1. USER -- Owner
2. [myorg]\Project Collection Administrators -- Owner (Inherited)
3. [myorg]\Project Collection Valid User --  Reader (Inherited)

**Via UI:**

When Feed was created via user interface, the following permissions are set:

1. USER -- Owner
2. [myorg]\Project Collection Administrators -- Owner (Inherited)
3. Project Collection Build Service (myorg) -- Contributor
4. [myproject]\Project Administrators -- Owner
5. [myproject]\Contributors --  Contributor
6. [myproject] Build Service (myorg)     -- Contributor

Only limited user/group is provided permission for feed created via REST API compared to feed created manually via UI.
Why is there a difference?

Comment: It depends on how we define the request body. This is the [simplest format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886974/10910450), if you want to define similar feed like what UI does, you need to define [permissions element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/create%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#request-body) also.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there a difference in feed permission settings when Azure
> artifact feeds are created “via UI” and “via REST API”?

The difference depends on how we write the [Request Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/create%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#request-body). My request body [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886974/10910450) only used three elements, so the request only creates a simple feed with name and default permission specified.

If you want to create a feed with same permissions like what UI does, you should also specify the **Permissions** element, something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Test12345",
    "hideDeletedPackageVersions": true,
    "permissions": [
        {
            "identityDescriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ServiceIdentity;xxxxxxxxxx",
            "role": 3
        },
        {
            "identityDescriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ServiceIdentity;xxxxxxxxxx",
            "role": 3
        },
        {
            "identityDescriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;xxxxxxxxxx",
            "role": 4
        },
        {
            "identityDescriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "role": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

With `permissions` element defined in request body, you can use the API to create new feed with the the same permissions when you do that via UI.

**In addition:**

As for how to find the ID(the xxxxxxxx in body above) of those permissions, you can use Edge browser(or other browsers) in F12 mode to get your corresponding IDs. For me:

1.Navigate to the page when creating the feed via UI:

[image]

2.In Edge, click F12 and clear the previous requests:

[image]

3.Click the `Create` button, and check the requests in F12 window:

[image]

4.Find the request above and check its body, we can find the IDs list easily:

[image]

[image]

Once you've found the IDs which represents the corresponding permissions in your org, you can create feed with permissions easily.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @Niraimathi You're welcome. If you get a chance to try my answer, feel free to let me know the result. If my answer resolves your issue, you could [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) so that other members could benefit from marked answer.

Comment: For project specific groups like " [myproject]\Contributors "  and  " [myproject]\Project Administrators " , it is not easy to get the identity descriptors associated with every project ...Example: " [myproject_1]\Contributors " , " [myproject_2]\Contributors ",  "[myproject_3]\Contributors " ...so on. Is there a way to get all the identityDescriptor and later filter out what is required.

Comment: @Niraimathi There's no direct api to return the SIDs you need. We can only get the descriptor of user/group via Users-list and Groups-list, see [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61220494/10910450). Then we can decode the returned descriptor into SID we need use C# code or what, see this [detailed blog](https://blog.devopsabcs.com/index.php/2019/06/24/one-project-to-rule-them-all-3/).

Comment: @Niraimathi The easiest way to do what you need is to follow my `In addition` above, you can specify specific permission via UI, check the request in F12 and copy the request body, then you can get the required SIDs easily.